# How to open an modal on clicking on submeuns in navigation bar

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, menuitem, submenu, simplemodal

I wants to create a page in which after clicking on menu it should open an submeuns and after clicking on the option of submeuns it show show an modal where I wants to display some information as per requirements
I am able to create a navigation bar menus and submeuns.
How to open an modal after clicking on Submeuns items.

Thanks

I try to create a Navigation bar with submeuns
Expecting:Model should open after clicking on submeuns.